# Does a DMA controller copy one word of memory at a time?

Tags: dma

A DMA controller greatly speeds up memory copy operations because the data in memory doesn't have to be read into the CPU.

From what I've read, DMA controllers can "copy a block of memory from one location to another" in one operation, but thinking about this at a low level, I'm guessing the DMA ultimately has to iterate over memory one word at a time. Is that correct? Is that one word per clock cycle? One word per two clock cycles? (one for read memory into the DMA, one for write to memory) Or does the DMA have a circuit that can somehow (I can't imagine how) copy large chunks of memory in one or two clock cycles?

If the CPU tells the DMA to copy 1024 bytes of memory from one address to another, how many clock cycles will the CPU have free to perform other tasks while waiting for the DMA to finish?

Is it possible to have an architecture where the DMA is doing a memory copy using one bus, while the CPU can access memory at the same time in a different area? Say, in a different bank?

I'm sure it's architecture dependent, so for the answers just pick one or more 8 or 16 bit home micros.

Comment: See [this Wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is architecture dependent. Usually there is a main memory bus, and one or more cache. All buses in the system are not required to be the same width. Memory buses are usually larger than processor words, it might be 64bits wide, so it loads 64bits at a time.
Then the destination might be the same memory bus, or PCIE, or even another bus that is memory mapped, in which case the transfers might be constrained by the destination bus width.

How many clock cycles are available again depend of how things are done. Usually in a µC the DMA triggers an interrupt when it is done, and the CPU does nothing. An other option is polling.

There are dual port memory but usually there is only 1 main memory bus. IIRC banks are usually a trick to avoid large addresses, but use the same memory bus.
Cache and bus arbitration are used to mitigate bus contention, the user really shouldn't care about that. You can have a look at your µC datasheet if you want reliable information.